# how to define forEach element and why in vanilla javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am getting this error when running my code(added below). I am not sure why I should define "b" as it is an element of forEach.

You can find the forEach under UI class. Can someone please help me understand where I am going wrong with. It might be somthing simple of a conceptual error, but I am unable to figure it out.

> app.js:36 Uncaught ReferenceError: b is not defined

```
//Book Class: Represents a Book
class Book {
  constructor(title, author, isbn) {
    this.title = title;
    this.author = author;
    this.isbn = isbn;
  }
}
// UI Class: Handle UI Tasks
class UI {
  static displayBooks() {
    const StoredBooks = [{
        title: "Book One",
        author: "John Doe",
        isbn: "3434434"
      },
      {
        title: "Book two",
        author: "Jane Doe",
        isbn: "4354545"
      }
    ];

    const books = StoredBooks;
    books.forEach((b) => {
      return UI.addBookToList(b);
    });

  }
  static addBookToList() {
    const list = document.querySelector("#book-list");
    const row = document.createElement("tr");

    row.innerHTML = `
                            <td>${b.title}</td>
                            <td>${b.author}</td>
                            <td>${b.isbn}</td>
                            <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm delete>X</a></td>
                            `;

    list.appendChild(row);
  }
}

// Store Clas: Handles Storage

// Event: Dislpay Books\
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", UI.displayBooks);

// Event: Add a Book

// Event Remove a Book
```

Comment: you need to pass the parameter to the function like this `static addBookToList(b)`.

Comment: you don't need the `return` in the `forEach` statement.

Comment: You don't need `return` before `UI.addBookToList(b)`. `forEach()` doesn't do anything with the return value of the function, and `UI.addBookToList()` doesn't return anything.

Comment: Returning a "function call" still has a side effect, though the value isn't needed anywhere. Remove `return`, and call the function only, after you've fixed `addBookToList` definition as Raj has suggested.

Comment: @RajKumar Thanks it's working as expected.